# Command Line Apex Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, commandline, etl

any one worked on command Line apex data loader in windows system,
I got an error, when I am checking the Verify encrypted command.

C:\Program files\salesforce.com\data loader\bin>Encrypt.bat –v  
I that command I got error[image]

> ERROR [main] security.EncryptionUtil main (EncryptionUtil.java:336) - Error decrypting string: 88a89f8626975fb54ab42104f223fe48, error: Given final block not properly padded

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most descriptive error message in the world, but I've seen it show up for two reasons:

1. You are missing the `Path to Key` as the third parameter:

[image]

2. The verification failed, and the encrypted value is not correct for the password and key combination.

Ultimately, what you are looking for is a response message like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Process for Command line data loader please verify the steps as mentioned below

1. Navigate to Program Files | Data Loader | bin in command prompt and run below command.

   ```
   encrypt.bat –g YOURSECRETKEY
   e.g. encrypt.bat –g Password
   ```
2. Copy the generated key in some text file i.e. `Key.txt` and save that file as in `C:\`
3. Now run below command to generate encrypted password

   ```
   encrypt.bat -e password "C:\Key.txt"
   ```
4. Make sure that password generated is correct by checking below command

   ```
   encrypt.bat -v generatedPassword "C:\Key.txt"
   ```

Comment: encrypt.bat -v generatedPassword "C:\Key.txt"                                                       I tried this command still I am getting an error.

Comment: you need to put the encrypted password that was generated by encrypt.bat -e password "C:\Key.txt" command and put the encrypted password in place of generatedPassword